# How to set a RadComboBox that is using a data source to a selected value in codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind, radcombobox, rad-controls

I have a RadComboBox that is bounded by a datasource. I set the datacource to select from a the database using a select query. Run I run the project, I get a complete list of items in the RadComboBox.

I want to set the RadComboBox to a selected value, or index in the codebehind. So the RadComboBox will have a value in it once the page is load, instead of it being empty.

I have tried to do this with the code like so:

```
RadComboBoxItem item = RCB_PO_NUM.FindItemByText("2000");
item.Selected = true;
```

But I get a null value in the debugger once I run the program. I have tried to put the code in the `Page_Load` , `Page_LoadComplete`, and `Page_Init` methods. It still comes back as an null value. Can some please tell me where I should put the code, so that it will not return a null value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a property on your viewModel for the selected item and bind the radion button's `SelectedItem` property to it.

Alternatively try this code in the `RCB_PO_NUM.DataBound` event handler.

```
RadComboBoxItem item = RCB_PO_NUM.FindItemByText("2000");
RCB_PO_NUM.SelectedItem = item;
```

Comment: Looking into it now. Thanks

Comment: I updated my answer. There should be DataBound event on that control.

Comment: That event handler never gets fired

Comment: That means you don't bind the control at all. You should bind DataSource then the event will fire. How do you populate the items?

Comment: I set the datacource to select from a the database using a select query. I can see all the items in the list drop down of the combobox once the page is loaded

Comment: I added SqlDataSourcePO_NUM.DataBind(); on the page_load method, the even still never gets fired

Comment: Are you sure you attach to the event not too late? Try also the Load and PreRender events of the control itself not the page.

Comment: I had the property load on demand set to true. I like that feature. Once I set it to false the RCB_PO_NUM.DataBound, I didn't need to set the SqlDataSourcePO_NUM.DataBind(), the event fired with out

Comment: I wish there was a way for me to keep the EnableLoadOnDemand property set the true